# How to display custom field in soap api v2 method salesOrderInfo

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, sales

I have created custom attribute Barcode. Each simple product has filled unique barcode value.

Where and what should I change to display it for each order items in output of method `salesOrderInfo`?

I have Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be solved by creating module.

Module files:

> app/code/local/YourCompany/Sales/etc/config.xml - module config file
>
> copy **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsi.xml** to **app/code/local/YourCompany/Sales/etc/wsi.xml** **and add your new fields**
>
> copy **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml** to **app/code/local/YourCompany/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml** **and add your new fields**
>
> app/code/local/YourCompany/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php - in my example

I'm adding custom fields: upc, style, color and size

```
<?php
class YourCompany_Sales_Model_Order_Api extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api{

    protected function _getAttributes($object, $type, array $attributes = null){

        $result = parent::_getAttributes($object, $type, $attributes);

        if( $type === 'order_item' ){
            $result['upc'] = $object->getProduct()->getData('barcode');

            $parent = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                ->getParentIdsByChild($object->getProduct()->getData('entity_id'));
            if( $parent ) $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parent[0]);

            $result['style'] = $parent ? $parent->getData('name') : '';

            $result['color'] = $object->getProduct()->getAttributeText('color');

            $result['size'] = $object->getProduct()->getAttributeText('size');

        }elseif( $type === 'order_address' ){
            if( $object->getData('country_id') !== 'US' ){

                $region = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->load($object->getData('region_id'));
                if( $region ) $result['region'] = $region->getCode();

                $country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode($object->getData('country_id'));
                if( $country ) $result['country_id'] = $country->getName();

            }
        }

        return $result;

    }

}
```

Comment: It's not very good at all. You don't need to copypaste full wsdl/wsi config (because configs are merged). You just need to add your new fields with necessary references.

Comment: Don't modify core files, beside this it looks like a proper solution

Comment: Why it needs to copy the whole wsdl/wsi configs? Isn't there a way to add only those new fields in our new configs? What will happen if another module do the same thing?

Comment: Alexandros, thank you fro your answer, but unfortunately I can't test your advice: no backups of that project. It was so long time ago...